# how to switch played music when someone enters

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, music

My wife has a small shop, and she plays free licensed music. She can't legally play her own music when people outside of the family circle are present in the shop.

How can I automatically switch music when someone enters? I was thinking of some bluetooth door detector and some custom software, but can't seem to find either. I'm a software architect/dev and can write it if necessary, but I'd prefer to use some existing solution.

Any ideas on good hardware and software for this?

Comment: Some kind of a simple switch circuit going into an AD converter monitoring signal levels, and into a COM port. Then a C program sends key presses, depending on the signal, into a media player with two playlists. The key press combination config in the media player could switch between playlists...

Comment: I'm not into electronics, so this would take me days with an arduino. Looks like a multiple-K$ project if I count my time, can't afford it.

Comment: call me lazy but a Pressure pad, wired direct to mouse button, reset after they leave. If your desperate to add wireless and possibility to fail more ways , a bluetooth mouse costs $7  tie it to the 4th or 5th button for a special macro using mouse macro software like x-mouse. Again easily tie a mouse into one of the light breaking door entry items, or magnetic reed switch assembly. Go wireless and you have to have batteries, then might want a charger for batts, and need a adapter and on and on, one wire direct sure solves a lot of stuff.

Comment: mmh, some interesting ideas here. Doesn't cost much. The mechanic setup looks difficult to me, though. Wireless is a must (can have a power supply but 4 metres from entrance to pc).

Comment: Here's a similar question elsewhere : http://www.instructables.com/answers/Use-a-door-switch-to-run-script-on-a-computer/

Comment: No problem with -1 in itself, but can you explain please?

Comment: @BrianAdkins yeah, but this would require me to do some soldering, which I never did well. And the mechanical part of the problem is still there, I'm not able to solve that properly ;-)